# Is it possible to install Win8 next to an encrypted Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, encryption, ssd

I run Ubuntu on an SDD (encrypted with systemtools since installation). So I want to install Windows 8 on a second partion on the same drive, but it is possible to do so, without chrashing anything, because Windows could overwrite parts of the encrypted Ubuntu System?

I hope you can answer my question or give me a little help ;)
Thanks for all answers I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Windows will not overwrite anything, because if it would, you would have a really broken ubuntu in all cases (not just when you encrypt it).

You do need some free space at a 'lower' level. You mention a second partition. If you have that partition (and are not using it), you're all set. If you don't you need to re-partition to get some space obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ;)
This means I can resize my main-partition without chrashing something and create a second partion for Windows 8.

Comment: Well, be advised that resizing is ALWAYS tricky! Backup before you do stuff like that obviously.